# Removing the 'Run As' popup in Win XP while launching an desktop app from IE

Tags: windows, popup, windows-xp, runas

We have developed an activex which launches a Desktop application from the Web application.
It works fine with Windows 7.
But in Windows XP whenever we try to launch the desktop application from web Application, the 'Run As' window pops up.

I have tried with setting up the username for both the option, still the 'Run As' window popup.
Any workaround as how to stop this popup from coming every time?

Regards